# AJAX Begin Form not Submitting

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use `AJAX.BeginForm` in my MVC Views. It doesn't give an error while debugging but i cannot submit the ajax form.

I have View like this :-
[image]

I have included the all the files which are required such as jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js.

In my Web.Config, i have the following :-

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

My Code :-

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateEvaluationDetails", "Recruitment", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
 {
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
 }
```

I have selected `CopyLocal = True` for System.Web.Mvc

Comment: did you add the reference of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax library?

Comment: That seems ok. Use the browser dev tools to debug the response.

Comment: You may be missing some js library. Do an inspect element and look in console for errors while submitting.